# Chance of getting at least a six throwing three dice depends on how we think about it?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

One throws three 6-sided dice (D1, D2, D3), to find out the probability of getting at least one six

Please help! I've banged my head on the wall for far too long! To this question, three approaches come to mind:

1. P(at least one six) = 1 - P(no six)
2. P(at least one six) = P(one six) + P(two six) + P(three six)

**3. P(at least one six) = Number of outcomes that satisfy at least one six / all outcomes**

I'd like to discuss the third way. To get at least one six, one die rolls six and the other two have no restrictions so the number of outcomes is:

1 (a die must be six) * 6 (no restrictions) * 6 (no restrictions) * 3 (ways to chose the chosen die) = 108

and the number of all outcomes is:

6 * 6 * 6

P(at least one six) = 108 / 216 = 0.5 which is not the same as the other two ways (91 / 216) of thinking!

What's going on here? What makes the third way overcount by 17?

Comment: By designating a particular six as the six that is rolled, you count each outcome with two sixes twice and the outcome three sixes three times, once for each way you could designate one of those sixes as the six that you rolled.  You should edit your question to show your calculations for the first two methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enumerate the outcomes with $k$ sixes, multiply the number of $k$-element subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$ by the number of non-six face on a die, $3-k$ times. Summing over $k\geqslant 1$ yields
$$
\sum_{k=1}^3 \binom 3k 5^{3-k} = 3\cdot5^2 + 3\cdot 5 +1=91.
$$
Note that $108=91+3\cdot 5+2$. Your logic counts the outcomes with $2$ sixes twice, and the outcome with $3$ sixes thrice.